# How can i get size of findRenderObject in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

in the old version there is a `Size` properties in `findRenderObject`, but now i cant find the `Size properties` in the `updated flutter version`

```
findButton() {
    final renderBox = _key.currentContext?.findRenderObject();
    buttonSize = renderBox?.size;
    buttonPosition = renderBox?.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
  }
```

both the `size` and `localToGlobal` is given me error

[image]

Comment: your `renderBox` is `RenderObject` not `RenderBox` - you need to cast it to `RenderBox`